# Conjugation of Irreducible {0,1}-Matrices by Orthogonal Matrix

Tags: matrix-theory

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be irreducible matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$. Let $S$ be an orthogonal matrix such that,

$A_1=SA_2S^T$

Is it necessarily the case that $S$ is a permutation matrix?

Comment: No, from the existence of cospectral graphs.

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense.